# PHP - Eclipse PDT require_once on linked folder

Tags: php, eclipse, require-once

I have 2 php projets in Eclipse PDT (1 for classes, 1 client using classes). I don't want to manually sync folders.
I created linked folders, which seems solving the pb (classes appears in the client project), but when i require it, i get the 'no such file' error.
Do I missed something ?

windows 7, apache 2, PHP 5

- ClientProject

  - derp.php
  - Classes [LinkedFolder]

    - V1

      - herp.php
- Classes

  - V1

    - herp.php

In derp.php

```
require_once('/Classes/V1/herp.php');
```

Comment: What does your require statement look like?

Comment: what if you don't link the folder, but set the include_path?

Comment: Same pb. (and obv working when I duplicate files)

Answer (score 0):

You can use full paths in `require_once`. Since you're on Windows, try:

```
require_once('C:/Work/Projects/derp/Classes/V1/herp.php');
```

Comment: Sure, but you can define the base path as a constant in your config files so it's easily changeable in dev/production environments.